# How to enable Next JS rewrite Text streaming response?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have an API call which uses the rewrite function of NextJS to reach the backend server:

```
      {
        source: '/django/:path*',
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/:path*",
      },
    ];
```

However, I've noticed that this does not stream my backend api response. Rather, if I call the endpoint directly, the streaming works.

```
const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/endpoint`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
      });
```

What is different about next JS and how can I receive a text streaming response?

Here is my frontend. I've ensured that the backend is working

```
const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/endpoint`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
      });

    
      let decoder = new TextDecoderStream();
      if (!response.body) return;
      const reader = response.body
        .pipeThrough(decoder)
        .getReader();
      
      while (true) {
        setLoading(true);
        var {value, done} = await reader.read();
        
        if (done) {
          break;
        } else {
          tmpPromptResponse += value;
          if (currentchatId === chatId) {
            setMarkdownContent(tmpPromptResponse + "▌");
          }
        }
      }
```